# Pandas won't read Excel XML 2003 file with `xls` extension

Tags: python, excel, pandas

Can anyone please tell me why pandas won't read Excel XML 2003 file with `xls` extension? When I try to read it from my Python script, it throws an error:

```
xlrd.biffh.XLRDError: Unsupported format, or corrupt file: Expected BOF record; found b'<html  x'
```

I know the obvious reason: it is actually a XML file with fake `xls` extension. But I can still open it with Excel: a normal spread sheet. I think that means there is still a way to read it from pandas?

If no luck, can I convert this Excel XML 2003 with `xls` extension into a "real" `xls` file without the XML tags by using Python script? If so I can just add this section of code in front of the PANDAS code to read the converted `xls` file.

Comment: Hi, Welcome to Stackoverflow. Can you add a minimum reproducible code to your question, It would be easier to check the issue that way.

Comment: Just for kicks, what happens if you try to read the renamed file with an xlsx extension?

Comment: Take the easy way out. Open it in Excel and save it as an `.xlsx`.

Comment: Hi S3DEV, 
I tried that, still the same error message.

Comment: Hi BoarGules, I have to put it into code as it has to be automated...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It should work if you make sure `openpyxl` is installed and explicitly tell Pandas to use that engine:

```
df = pd.read_excel("foo.xls", engine="openpyxl")
#                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

[Pandas can use one of four underlying engines when ingesting Excel files](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html#pandas.read_excel). The one it uses for `xls` files doesn't support the newer formats:

> If io is not a buffer or path, this must be set to identify io. Supported engines: "xlrd", "openpyxl", "odf", "pyxlsb". Engine compatibility:
>
> - "xlrd" supports old-style Excel files (.xls).
> - "openpyxl" supports newer Excel file formats.
> - "odf" supports OpenDocument file formats (.odf, .ods, .odt).
> - "pyxlsb" supports Binary Excel files.
>
> *Changed in version 1.2.0:* The engine xlrd now only supports old-style `.xls` files. When `engine=None`, the following logic will be used to determine the engine:
>
> - If `path_or_buffer` is an OpenDocument format (.odf, .ods, .odt), then odf will be used.
> - Otherwise if `path_or_buffer` is an xls format, `xlrd` will be used.
> - Otherwise if `path_or_buffer` is in xlsb format, `pyxlsb` will be used.
>   *New in version 1.3.0.*
> - Otherwise `openpyxl` will be used.
>   *Changed in version 1.3.0.*

Comment: Thank you. Tried engine="openpyxl", got this error message: openpyxl.utils.exceptions.InvalidFileException: openpyxl does not support the old .xls file format, please use xlrd to read this file, or convert it to the more recent .xlsx file format.

Comment: And you're entirely sure this is actually an XLSX format file? Why does it have the wrong extension in the first place?

Comment: Hi Chris, it is a XLS format, not a XLSX. The thing is because it is generated from our legacy system, it is using XLS.

Comment: To be honest, I am not 100% sure. When opening the file, it pops up a window "The file format and extension of '<this file>.xls' don't match. The file could be corrupted or unsafe. Unless you trust its source, don't open it. Do you want to open it anyway?" I click Yes, then it will open it in excel. But if you view it in Notepad, it shows the xml stuff. I seems like a xml file with xls extension, but the strange thing is you can still open it with excel

Comment: An XLSX file isn't _exactly_ XML. It's a _zip archive containing several XML files_, so I'm surprised that Notepad shows anything readable. It should look mostly like nonsense. Where did this file come from? Fixing the source of the error is likely a better solution than dealing with it downstream.

Comment: It is a system auto-generated file from a legacy system. If I manually open it with excel and save it as a xls file, pandas can read it OK. So I think I am just going to use script to convert it into a "real" xls file before pandas can read it.

Comment: Hi Chris, I know why. The stupid system actually generated it as a HTML file with xls extension...... That was why all these confusion comes from. How would I convert it into a proper xls by using Python script? I can manually open it with excel and save as a xls file, pandas can read it OK. I just want to automate this process.

Comment: It would depend on exactly what the HTML format is. Without more information I'm not sure what to tell you.